# How to use MaxValue with booleans?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, boolean-computation

I tried to use [*MaxValue*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxValue.html) on `Booleans` domain:

```
MaxValue[{x + y, Element[x|y, Booleans]},{x,y}]
```

However, it fails with `Variable domain Booleans should be either Reals or Integers`.

How to circumvent this limitation and use *MaxValue* with booleans? I would expect this to return *2*.

Comment: You cannot add Booleans. Use `Or` to see if any are `True`

Comment: Could also try the `Boole` function to convert the Boolean True and False values into their corresponding 1 or 0

Comment: @JoshuaSchrier I tried `MaxValue[{Boole[x] + Boole[y]},Element[x|y, Booleans], PositiveIntegers]` but it does not resolve.

Comment: Why not just formulate it as a 0-1 problem? `MaxValue[{x + y, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1}, {x, y}, Integers]`

Comment: @J.M. That was what I was looking for, thanks. Feel free to post a full answer so I can accept it.